# How to scale game viewport?

Tags: javascript, css, html, math

I make game using HTML5/CSS/JS. And now I have problem that I can't solve. **How to scale game to any screen resolution?** Maybe it's simple, but not for me.

**SOLVED**

```
var RATIO = 480 / 800; // Original ratio.
function resize() {
    var DEVICE_WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
        DEVICE_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
        ratio = DEVICE_WIDTH / DEVICE_HEIGHT,
        scale = 1;
    // If window changes by height we calculate scale parameter fo width
    if (ratio > RATIO) { 
        scale = DEVICE_HEIGHT / 800; // Devide by original viewport height
    } else { // If window changes by width we calculate scale parameter for height
        scale = DEVICE_WIDTH / 480; // Devide by original viewport width
    }
}

// So, now you can continue make your game, but in draw method you have to multiply 
// everything by this scale parameter (x and y coords, width and height)
```

Hope it'll help somebody like me :)

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you've named your canvas, `canvas`. The code to change its size without stretching it is as follows:

```
function setSize(width, height)
{
    canvas.width = width; 
    canvas.style.width = width + "px";
    canvas.height = height; 
    canvas.style.height = height + "px";
}

//And then to use that,
setSize(350, 200);
```

Comment: I don't use canvas for this game, CSS only. How scale everything to proper resolution? Thanks for answering by the way :)

Comment: Oh gosh, scaling html games? I guess I wouldn't give anything a fixed width. Give it a percentage instead. If that doesn't work you would likely need to do it with javascript

Answer (score 0):

You would set it dynamically as you want to for eg. If your container have some id or class you could

```
var container = document.getElementById(idName);

var resize = function(element) {
    return function (width, height) {
          element.style.width = width;
          element.style.height = height;
     }
}

var sizeListener = resize(container)(document.documentElement.clientWidth,document.documentElement.clientHeight);
```

Comment: but how to scale container's objects, scene objects?